# Code for a random secret number

Tags: python, python-3.4

The code allows me more than six times for input and also it did not print   the `else` statement. My code is:

```
import random
secret = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0
print ('AHOY! I am the Dread Prites Roberts , and i have a secret!')
print ('It is a number from 1 to 99. I\'ll give you 6 tries ')

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
guess = int(input('What is your guess? '))
if guess < secret:
     print ('Too Low, you scurvy dog!')
elif guess > secret:
     print ('Too high, boy')
     tries = tries + 1
elif guess == secret: 
     print ('Avast! you got it ! Found my seceret , you did!')
else:
     print ('No more guess! Better Luck next time')
     print ('The secret number was',secret)
```

I tried the code in Python 3.4. It prints the result more than six times. While guess is not equal to secret and tries... after 6 tries it will print `'No more guess better luck next time'` but is executing again and again

Answer (score 4):

your have an indentation problem (i guess happened by pasting) but your main problem is, that you are only incrementing `tries` when the guess was too high. Also you should move the last if else out of the while block, since the while condition is already taking care of vars.

Your implementation should look like this:

```
import random
secret = random.randint(1, 99)
guess = 0
tries = 0
print ('AHOY! I am the Dread Prites Roberts , and i have a secret!')
print ('It is a number from 1 to 99. I\'ll give you 6 tries ')

while guess != secret and tries < 6:
    guess = int(input('What is your guess? '))
    tries = tries + 1
    if guess < secret:
         print ('Too Low, you scurvy dog!')
    elif guess > secret:
         print ('Too high, boy')

if guess == secret: 
    print ('Avast! you got it ! Found my seceret , you did!')
else:
    print ('No more guess! Better Luck next time')
    print ('The secret number was',secret)
```